Replacing the first beam splitter with polarizing beam splitter in the Mach-Zehnder Interferometer
For the single-photon interference in a Mach Zehnder Interferometer, if we replace the first beam splitter with a polarizing beam splitter, what would happen? Would the single photon still interfere with itself again at the second (non-polarizing) beam splitter?

The problem comes from this paper (arXiv version), where the author used the same setup to measure the path qubit (in the computational basis $|0\rangle, |1\rangle$ and the phase basis ($|0\rangle + e^{i\theta}|1\rangle$) ) of the photon, while not disturbing the polarization qubit of the photon. If this tweaked interferometer cannot interfere the single photon with itself at the second (non-polarizing) beam splitter, then isn't it simply impossible to measure the path qubit in the phase basis?

Edit: I realize that the setup in the paper indeed can independently perform the path measurement and the polarization measurement. The setup works exactly because of the second beam splitter being non-polarizing, rather than polarizing. If photons with different polarization were to interfere with each other (which is impossible), then the path measurement would disturb the polarization measurement and vice versa.

The MZ apparatus has modes (allowable paths for photons) ... for example if both arms are tuned to lambda + 0.5 no transmission occurs in either arm!  In your case the PBS adds another constraint but assuming the light is non-polar  the EM field (modes) will still allow transit in either arm.

If we represent the path information in a two dimensional Hilbert space $\mathcal H_W$ spanned by $|L\rangle,|R\rangle$, a non-polarizer beam splitter act as a rotation (assuming perfect 50:50 ratio)
$$
U_{BS} |L\rangle = 2^{-1/2} (|L\rangle + |R\rangle), \quad 
U_{BS} |R\rangle = 2^{-1/2} (|L\rangle - |R\rangle)
$$
If we add polarization $|+\rangle,|-\rangle$, nothing changes in equations above, since the operator in the total Hilbert space $\mathcal H_W \otimes \mathcal H_P$ will be $U_{BS}\otimes \mathrm I_P$.
The PBS on the other hand, acts in the full space $\mathcal H_W \otimes \mathcal H_P$ as
$$
U_{PBS} |L\rangle (|+\rangle \pm |-\rangle) = |L\rangle |+\rangle \pm |R\rangle |-\rangle \quad U_{PBS} (|L\rangle \pm |R\rangle) |+\rangle= |L\rangle |+\rangle \quad U_{PBS} (|L\rangle \pm |R\rangle) |-\rangle= |R\rangle |-\rangle 
$$
The polarization acts like a path discriminator. Let's work out two input states
If the input state have well defined path and polarization, like $|L\rangle|+\rangle$, it will remain so after PBS (this state doesn't affected by PBS), and after the final BS, the state will be
$$
2^{-1/2} (|L\rangle + |R\rangle)|+\rangle
$$
Showing no interference, there will be clicks in both detectors.
If the initial state are in a superposition of polarization and well defined path state, like $|L\rangle (|+\rangle + |-\rangle)$, the PBS will give the entangled state described above, and after the final BS, we would have the state
$$
|L\rangle (+\rangle + |-\rangle) + |R\rangle (|+\rangle - |-\rangle)
$$
And again, there is no interference, but the states end in different polarizations.
The initial state with well defined polarization and path superposition would not add anything new. The conclusion: the PBS destroy the interference effect!
It happens due to Which-path information, contained in the polarization of light after the first PBS. To recover the interfere fringes, we should erase this information, with some operation in the total Hilbert space (like another PBS).
